# How to restore database file to joomla local database?

Tags: wordpress, joomla, phpmyadmin

I am supposed to migrate a website from `joomla` to `wordpress` and to do so I have to restore the website backup to joomla. I have the complete(I suppose) backup of the website database which I was given in a `.tar` file. I figured the backup was created from `plesk`(do not know if this is important) and it was sent to me in the `.tar` format. When I installed `Joomla` I created a database on phpmyadmin localhost page which I used to install `Joomla`.
My question is how do I restore the database to my local Joomla installation.
This is the structure of the `.tar` file I have.
[image: Structure]
In the databases folder I have 2 subfolders, each of which have `.tgz`,  file and they in turn have a a file with no extension called backup_xxxx(some different number).
I know that a backup file has `.sql` extension so what is the correct way to restore this website backup as a whole

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to create a new empty data base and pull the sql into it. Then see if the structure matches the structure of what you installed in your Joomla instance.  If so, go to global configuration and switch to the data base you imported.  Note that there are a number of settings in the global configuration file that you will have to change including the data base name, the prefix, the user and the password.